# Retrieving App Service list from Azure using C# Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent is resulting in 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to use the Fluent libraries in a C# web application in order to retrieve a list of application services from Azure.

My problem is that function calls to do so are throwing an exception *"'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null. "*.

The way I'm authenticating is using the FromServicePrinciple call:

```
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(ApplicationID, AuthKey, TenantID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

Then creating an interface;

```
IAzure az = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
```

As far as I can tell, the applicationid and tenantid are correct, because otherwise I get a different exception that says the application cannot be found.  I also cant see how I could have gotten the authkey wrong since I just created it.

When I examine *az.SubscriptionId* at this point it is null, which I'm guessing it shouldn't be.

So, when I call

```
var appservicelist = az.AppServices.List();
```

or

```
var webapplist = az.WebApps.List();
```

I get the exception.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this is, or what I need to change in Azure in order for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try set subscription? I work on java, it allows me set subscription. `IAzure az = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(<sub id>)`

Comment: Do you have subscription in your tenant?

Comment: I think you're right.  All the example source that I've looked at has all been using .WithDefaultSubscription().  Not sure why this wouldn't work, but I think I'm going to have to create another subscription with appropriate permissions if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure you have subscription in your tenant. If you don't set default subscription, you could set subscription in your code.

```
IAzure az = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription("3b4d41fa-****-4bc7-bc11-***");
```

Note: Replace your subscription id.

Comment: This was definitely it.  Probably because we  have more than one subscription.  I had previously tried both subscriptions explicitly, but they both failed. Must have been a different error though. Now I've created a resource group within the subscription its not throwing that exception anymore, but I'm just getting no results.  fun fun fun ;)